# Exclamation mark in red box on top of the screen with white lines on both sides

Tags: screen, samsung-galaxy-s, android-11, samsung-galaxy-s-10, overlay

I have a Samsung Galaxy S10 5G and my Android version is Android 11. While using one of the regular apps that I use every day, I noticed that a red box with an exclamation mark inside appeared on the top of the screen.

[image: a portrait screen example]

[image: a landscape screen]

Also, two lines on both sides of the screen appeared and they rotate with the screen. I don't understand how this issue started it just came from nowhere.

Please advise what to do. By the way, the box and the two-line do not appear on the lock screen.

Comment: Looks like a screen overlay. "*While using one of the regular apps that I use every day*" could you mention the apps? They might be related to the overlay.

Comment: MX Video Player

Answer (score 1):

Your 'Switch-Access' in accessibility is activated. Go into settings and deactivate it & the red box with an exclamation mark will go away. I dont know off hand exactly where in settings they are but you can search for it as soon as you pull up settings by tapping the search bar. My accessibility settings menu is always available at the bottom corner of my screen. I set it that way in settings. The exclamation box only appears for me when 'Switch-Access'is activated.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Setting - Apps & Notification - All apps - Android Accessibility Suite - Force stop.
In case if it doesn't work then restart the device in Safe mode and repeat "Step 1".

Good luck! (Y)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).